# Accumulating list of result to a dictionnary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking for an elegant and performant way of accumulating results of an algorithm into an accumulator.

```
accumulator = { "k1": 15, "k2": 0, "k3": 12}
# Output of the algorithm values[i] matches keys[i]
keys = ["k1", "k2", "k3"]
values = [ 12,   13 ,  14]
```

Here two solutions that solve my problem, but I am not convinced that there are the best one.

Simple for loop

```
for i in range(0, len(keys)):
    accumulator[keys[i]] += values[i]
```

Using a generator

```
accumulator = {keys[i]: accumulator[i] + values[i] for i in rage(0, len(keys))}
```

Edit:
 - All the keys of the dictionary will be present in the list of keys.

Comment: Your generator version will lose any entries in `accumulator` that aren't also in `keys`.

Comment: That is not a problem, all the keys present in the accumulator will be in the list of keys (i edited the question).

Comment: D’you want to create a `dict(zip(keys, values))` and update a `Counter` with it? (Not appropriate for things that aren’t counts, mind.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Counter, in collections

```
from collections import Counter

keys = ["k1", "k2", "k3"]
values = [ 12,   13 ,  14]

c = Counter({ "k1": 15, "k2": 0, "k3": 12})
# to update value of k1 -this works even if k1 is not present
c.update(zip(keys, values))
```

Comment: Didn't know about counter, the data structure fit perfectly the use case

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
for k, v in zip(keys, values):
    accumulator[k] += v
```

It's very similar to your first version, just slightly more concise.  This will only work if `k` is already present in `accumulator`, unless you use a `defaultdict` for `accumulator`.